# Installing msi on remote computer ( ManagementException "Not found" )

Tags: c#, exception, windows-installer, wmi

I'm currently working on trying to install an msi on a remote computer using WMI, and I've ran into a bit of a problem which I can't figure out.

When I use the following code on a WMI connection to the local computer its running from, it works fine. But when I change the connection to a remote computer it throws an ManagementException at

```
    object res = installer.InvokeMethod("Install", methodArgs);
```

with the message "Not found".

I've verified that both the WMI connection to the remote computer is working fine and that the msi file is located correctly.

```
try
{
    ManagementClass installer = new ManagementClass(scope, new ManagementPath("Win32_Product"), new ObjectGetOptions());

    object[] methodArgs = { @"C:\Deploy\Deploy.msi", @"TARGETDIR=C:\", true };
    object res = installer.InvokeMethod("Install", methodArgs);

    if ((UInt32)res != 0)
        throw new Exception("Install error " + res.ToString());
    else                                                       
        project.Log(Level.Info, "Succesfully installed {0}", msi);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    project.Log(Level.Error, ex.ToString());  
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the file exist on C:\Deploy\Deploy.msi on the remote machine?

Comment: Yes, I've verified that the file is located correctly.

Comment: Ok, the normal reason is forgetting that the install actually runs on the remote machine and hence the file has to be on the remote machine and not your machine that starts the file. Don't see anything wrong with your code, and I had used something like that myself. Can you try checking the event log on the remote machine and and also change the install to create a log file which gave further clues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've figured it out;

The machine I tried installing to was running Server 2003, which does not have Windows Install Provider installed by default. ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392726%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

I changed the destination machine to one running Windows 7, and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I remember I had to use below format to start up the process:

```
ManagementClass theClass = new ManagementClass(@"\\server\root\cimv2:Win32_Process");
```